# .htaccess not triggered

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I have the following .htaccess in my /var/www/site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ parser.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have allowed override in my vhost:

```
<Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

**UPDATE:**
Now I got it to work, however when I visit site.com, it also redirects me to this parser.php, in which I don't want as this is my homepage.
My homepage should be redirected to index.php and if I do mysite/NASKDj, it should be redirected to parser.php?pid=NASKDj. How do I fix this?

Comment: permissions OK on the .htaccess file? Do other .htacess files work on the same web server?

Comment: That's a pretty open `RewriteRule`. Unless you're intention is to match *everything*, I'd suggest making it more strict.

Comment: see my update above, I am missing some info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 'AllowOverride None' in the '/var/www/site' directory - this will overrive the one specified in the '/' directory. If your site is in /var/www/site you need to change This one to All too.

Comment: Last try, I am not an expert, someone may be able to help with RewriteCond's but try: RewriteBase /parser.php

Comment: actually my homepage is at index.php so I did RewriteBase /index.php and the main page works, but not the /parser.php?id=NASKDKsa

Answer (score 0):

I just saw `AllowOverride None` in your `<Directory /var/www/site>...</Directory>`, So?